# NetworkAdapter-Addresses of Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, proximity

I'm trying to build a Windows-Phone-8 App which communicates over several network-interfaces (Bluetooth, Wifi, maybe NFC)

My question:
Is there any way to get the Addresses (MAC / IP) of these Adapters (Bluetooth / Wifi)?!

For proxmity-adapters I tried already ->

```
ProximityDevice tempDevice = ProximityDevice.GetDefault();

string deviceSelector = ProximityDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
```

Thanks in advance!